# Why can't I derive from System.Enum abstract class?

Tags: c#, .net

MSDN defines System.Enum as an abstract class:

```
[SerializableAttribute]
[ComVisibleAttribute(true)]
public abstract class Enum : ValueType, IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible
```

And also MSDN make such statement about abstract class:

> An abstract class cannot be
>   instantiated. The purpose of an
>   abstract class is to provide a common
>   definition of a base class that
>   multiple derived classes can share.

But I simply cannot derive from System.Enum. According to Jeffery Richter in his book "CLR via C#", it is C# compiler that forbid that derivation.

And I checked System.Enum's members, most of them are static, which is reasonable for it cannot be instantiated and static methods don't need an object instance to invoke. But there are also some instance methods, such a GetHashCode() and GetTypeCode().

> So, my first question is, if System.Enum cannot
>   be instantiated or derived, how could
>   these *instance methods* be invoked?
>   Isn't this some kind of a paradox?
>
> I know I could use the following
>   approach to invoke these instance
>   methods, but why? Is there some kind
>   of System.Enum or derived type *object
>   instance* created? When? and by whom?

```
public enum Days:byte { Saturday, Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday };
Days d = Days.Friday;
d.GetTypeCode();
d.GetHashCode();
```

Comment: Days does derive from enum... what's your confusion?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can derive from `Enum`, e.g.

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    // ...
}
```

Will be compiled down to something like:

```
.class public auto ansi sealed MyEnum
    extends System.Enum
{
    // ...
}
```

The restriction the C# compiler places is that it won't let you write the derivation manually, but instead requires you to use the `enum` keyword when declaring the type.

As to why this is... my guess is because enumerations are a bit weird in the CLR. For example, the `ValueType` and `Enum` base types are both themselves reference types, not value types. There's a whole bunch of magic going on under the covers, and if you force the use of a keyword and prevent derivation from the magic base class, then you are keeping your intent separate from the magic.

Comment: Thanks, Greg. Your answer partially solved my problem. Now I am wondering why not allow us just extends the System.Enum directly?

Comment: @smwikipedia - Just added my guess as to why this is. You'd have to get one of the C# language designers to verify it though (Eric Lippert is on here regularly so he might stop by with any luck).

Comment: thanks, I have sent a mail to Eric Lippert and hope he could reply soon.

Comment: Couldn't have said it better myself. :-)  Note that we also do not allow you to derive from System.ValueType or System.Delegate directly either. Types like System.Enum are *very special types*. We can't let people say ridiculous things like "class List<T> : System.Delegate" and expect it to work.

Comment: Thanks, Eric. I feel much better now. 8^D

Answer (score 0):

Enums are value type that why you can't instanctiate or derive from it. Instance methods such as GetHashCode() are just present for reference type objects such as classes.