# Are all objects that don't inherit from System.ValueType reference type?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, value-type, reference-type

Am I correct in believing that **any** object that doesn't inherit from [System.ValueType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.valuetype.aspx) must therefore by definition be a reference type?

I've been unable to find any conclusive documentation to backup this notion.

Comment: see here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3503568/system-valuetype-understanding

Comment: Pointers are neither.  Can't call them an object though.

Comment: @HansPassant You could be deliberately obtuse and say that they are objects in another sense of the word (they'd be called objects in C for example). Still, you'd have to be really deliberately obtuse to say that, they aren't what is meant by "object" in the .NET world.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check if [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173104.aspx) helps.

[image]

Comment: `System.ValueType` also inherits from `System.Object`. Thus by this logic, all value types are reference types.

Comment: (Above comment is no longer valid after AkharRoop edited to include the graphic.)

Answer (score 1):

If you read closely the [Remarks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.valuetype.aspx#remarksToggle) you'll see that

> Data types are separated into value types and reference types. Value
>   types are either stack-allocated or allocated inline in a structure.
>   Reference types are heap-allocated. Both reference and value types are
>   derived from the ultimate base class Object. **In cases where it is
>   necessary for a value type to behave like an object, a wrapper that
>   makes the value type look like a reference object is allocated on the
>   heap, and the value type's value is copied into it.** The wrapper is
>   marked so the system knows that it contains a value type. This process
>   is known as boxing, and the reverse process is known as unboxing.
>   Boxing and unboxing allow any type to be treated as an object.

C# compiler does a wonderful job making you think that value types like `int` `long` has methods

Comment: They do have methods. It's not an illusion.

Comment: @Eric though the compiler does do a lovely job of helping the jitter invoke them efficiently on our behalf thanks to the constrained opcode ;)

Comment: @Eric Lippert: If I have a struct (e.g. `System.Collections.Generic.List`1+Enumerator[System.Int32]`) and invoke a method on a boxed instance (e.g. `IEnumerable<Int32>`.MoveNext()), does the system directly call the same method as if I invoke the method on the struct, or does it invoke something else?  It doesn't seem to unbox the instance, since mutations performed by the function affect the boxed instance.  My interpretation of the behavior is that there's a wrapper function which calls the requested function on the boxed object.  Is that how things work?

Comment: @Eric Lippert: At what stage does that happen?  Does CallVirt examine the type of the target and determine that it's expecting a value ref rather than a heap reference, or does the vtable point to a wrapper method that takes care of that?  Doing the check within CallVirt would seem to impair efficiency in the common case.

Answer (score 0):

If you were on QI and Stephen Fry was doing his normal thing of being what an impressionable idiot thinks a smart person is like, then he'd have reacted to "any object that doesn't inherit from System.ValueType must therefore by definition be a reference type" with a klaxon and a flashing screen saying "all objects are value types or reference types".

He'd then go on to point out that originally in computer science, *object* meant any entity that could be manipulated by a computer, and therefore includes pointers, which .NET has, even though they are don't fit the later definition of *object* (the word *later* said with a certain tone of condescension) that refers to objects that are encapsulated with their methods, and therefore you're wrong.

Alan Davies would point out that everyone knew what you meant, but it would be too late, your statement would have served only to fuel Fry's warm glow of smugness, especially since technology comes perhaps second only to Oscar Wilde in the ranks of things he likes to think he can talk intelligently about (and perhaps second to none in the ranks of things he knows nothing about, now I think of it, there's no way he'd manage to say the above and not get it wrong in some way).

In other words yes, you are completely right :)

(Apologies to those who haven't seen much British television, and therefore don't have a clue what any of that meant).

Comment: I tend to turn over when QI comes on ;-)

Comment: Wise choice. Unfortunately my kids often won't, so I just point out mistakes and "correct" answers that are merely playing with the semantics.