# Why Delegate and MulticastDelegate classes are not considered as base class?

Tags: c#, inheritance, delegates

When I inherit Delegate or MulticastDelegate classes I am getting compiler error, both are normal abstract classes only even though why I am unable to inherit these classes.

Could you please tell me any one why these classes are not considered as base class?

Comment: Dupe: [why-cant-i-derive-from-system-enum-abstract-class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324667/why-cant-i-derive-from-system-enum-abstract-class)

Answer (score 11):

Because it is very, very important that objects of a derived class of MulticastDelegate are *immutable*.  Which ensures that state cannot get corrupted when arbitrary code you don't know about subscribes an event handler. Immutability in .NET is implemented by *convention*, you make fields private, don't provide property setters, don't provide a default constructor.

This is not a trait that can be inherited, you could derive a class for an immutable base class and make it mutable.  And violate the immutability requirement.

So the compiler has a hard-baked rule about it and rejects your attempt at deriving from MulticastDelegate yourself.  It reserves the right, insisting it can only do it properly itself, you have to use the *delegate* keyword.  And does more, it automatically creates proper declarations for the Invoke() and BeginInvoke() methods, declarations that force you to use these methods in a type-safe way.

This will not slow you down.

Answer (score 6):

Because they are special classes, reserved for the CLR

[MSDN Says:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.multicastdelegate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> MulticastDelegate is a special class. Compilers and other tools can
>   derive from this class, but you cannot derive from it explicitly. The
>   same is true of the Delegate class.